# Excel 2013 - Closest guess to a certain time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am trying to come up with a function for E2 that looks at the times in the following cells (H2,J2,L2,N2, and P2) and show the corresponding name that is closest to the time/value of C2.

I tried something like this, but get `#Value!`

```
{=INDEX((H2,J2,L2,N2,P2,R2,T2,V2),MATCH(MIN(ABS((H2,J2,L2,N2,P2,R2,T2,V2)-$C2)),ABS((G2,I2,K2,M2,O2,Q2,S2,U2)-$C2),0))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the header values so that you can use whole ranges, e.g to get the winning name

> =INDEX(G2:U2,MATCH(MIN(IF(H$1:V$1="Time",ABS(H2:V2-C2))),IF(H$1:V$1="Time",ABS(H2:V2-C2)),0))

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER